# why is the url in django not reading the primary key and just reading it like a string?

Tags: django

```
def lead_update(request,pk) :
lead = Lead.objects.get(id=pk)
form = LeadForm()
if request.method == "POST" :
    form = LeadForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid() :
        first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        age = form.cleaned_data['age']
        lead.first_name = first_name
        lead.last_name = last_name
        lead.age = age
        lead.save()
        return redirect("/leads/{{ lead.pk }}/") # the problem

context = {
    "form" : form,
    "lead" : lead
}
return render(request,"leads/lead_update.html",context)
```

on debug : it is showing
The current path, leads/{{ lead.pk }}/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: could you please share your urls.py and lead_update.html ?

Comment: Thanks everyone , the problem was that i was using namespace : 'leads' in my urls.py and i wasn't using it in the redirect

Comment: redirect( 'leads:lead-details, pk = lead.pk ) , using this it works, here lead-detail is the name of the path('<int:pk>/', lead_detail, name='lead-detail') and lead_detail is the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{}}` is used inside templates not in `views.py`

If your `urls.py` is for e.g.

```
path('lead/<pk>/', views.lead_update, name='lead_update')
```

Then you can redirect as

```
return redirect('lead_update', pk=lead.pk)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an absolute and hard-coded url which is not recommended here:

```
return redirect(f"/leads/{ lead.pk }/") # only single curly brackets
```

But instead use reverse():

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse


return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('lead-update', args=[lead.pk]))
```

Name of url as suggested by user8193706, Urls.py:

```
path('lead/<pk>/', views.lead_update', name='lead_update')
```